# php program not displaying results

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using scite editor for php programs. It is not displaying an error message when I run a code, all I get is

> php -f "testsample.php"
>
> Exit code: 255

I'm trying to do the php program for automation through selenium RC. Is this an issue with scite or is there any particular settings that have to be done. Also, is there a particular IDE which is perfect for executing php codes for selenium rc?

Answer (score 0):

Means that your program ended abnormally. You probably have more error output that isn't showing.

Try to run `testsample.php` with `error_reporting(-1)` on the first line (to activate error_reporting).

And please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and try to follow Stack Overflow's (SO) guidelines.